# ibm infosphere metadata asset manager updates to assets by source

Tags: datastage, ibm-information-server, information-server

I am starting a new information server (version 11.7), and i did my first import of metadata int o the metadata asset manager then import into datastage.

Here's where I am having issues.  What happens if the source table changes?  Is there any point in metadata asset manager that will auto update the asset list? or is this a manual process? If this can be set to auto-refresh, where?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no auto-refresh feature. The source metadata has to be re-imported manually from the metadata asset manager UI or there's command-line option to re-import using which the whole process can be automated.

[IBM Knowledge center link for command-line usage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.mmi.doc/topics/r_using_command_line.html)